# how to convert 12hrs format time to utc in android

Tags: android, datetime-format, utc

getting wrong results after converting 12hrs time format to utc.

```
 String inputPa = "hh:mm a";
            String OutPa = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
            SimpleDateFormat inputPatter = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPa);
            SimpleDateFormat outputPatter = new SimpleDateFormat(OutPa);

            Date date1 = null;
            String str1 = null;

            try {
                date1 = inputPatter.parse(txtStartTime.getText().toString());
                str1 = outputPatter.format(date1);
                Log.d("mycheck", str1);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: You need to post the error you are getting

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: What is your expected result given that the input doesn’t seem to have a date? And how does your observed result differ?

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

I assumed you wanted today’s date in your time zone.

```
    String inputPa = "hh:mm a";
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter12Hours = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputPa, Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Detroit");

    String timeString = "11:34 AM";

    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, timeFormatter12Hours);
    Instant inst = LocalDate.now(zone).atTime(time).atZone(zone).toInstant();

    System.out.println(inst);
```

Output from this example is:

> 2020-05-30T15:34:00Z

I would not bother converting the `Instant` to a string explicitly. It prints in UTC in your desired format when you print it, thus implicitly invoking its `toString` method (the format is ISO 8601, the international standard).

Please fill in your desired time zone. To rely on the device’ time zone setting set `zone` to `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

I am of course happy to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. You can do that on your Android version too, see the details below.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

```
public tring getCurrentUTC(Date time) {
    SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    outputFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return outputFmt.format(time);
}
```

You can use this code to get current UTC time.

For you question, you just need convert the time string to the `Date` format.